# How can I limit table column width?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, css-tables

One of the columns in my table can contain a long text without whitespaces. How can I limit its width to, say, 150px? I don't want it to be 150px always (if it's empty it should be narrow), but if there is a long text I want it to be limited with 150px and the text to be wrapped.

Here is a test example: http://jsfiddle.net/Kh378/ (let's limit the 3rd column).

Thank you in advance.

**Update:**
Setting this styles:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
max-width: 150px;
```

does not work in IE8 (tested on different computers) and I suppose it does not work in any version of IE.

Comment: As this question is almost three years old and it currently does not have a bounty, I was wondering whether it still needs an answer?

Comment: The question was answered in [another StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18367959/table-columns-setting-both-min-and-max-width-with-css). In short, you should just use width instead of max-width.

Comment: @Frank Conijn, Yes, it does! :)

Comment: That 2 years later reply though

Comment: The answer won't change, so the age does not matter :)

Answer (score 97):

[Updated](http://jsfiddle.net/Kh378/1/)

On the table's `td` and `th` tags I added:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
max-width: 150px;
```

Not fully compatible in every browser but a start.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work in IE8 (and I suppose it does not work in any version of IE...).

Comment: Can this be done as a percentage, because it only takes effect as px on my end...

Answer (score 15):

You need to use width instead.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>                
            <th style="width: 150px;"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

But just in the `<thead>` section.

Comment: What if you don't have a `<thead>` section?

Answer (score 8):

You should be able to style your column with:

```
max-width: 150px; 
word-wrap: break-word;
```

Note that `word-wrap` is supported in IE 5.5+, Firefox 3.5+, and WebKit browsers (Chrome and Safari).

Comment: See this in more detail, especially the max-width and (currently) the problems there, in the similar/equivalent solution this page http://stackoverflow.com/a/24620364/2255628

Answer (score 5):

After some experimentation in Chrome I came to the following:

- if your table has a `<th>` that should have either a "width" or a "max-width" set
- the `<td>`'s must have set a "max-width" and "word-wrap: break-word;"

If you use a "width" in the `<th>` its value will be used. If you use a "max-width" in the `<th>` the "max-width" value of the `<td>`'s is used instead.

So this functionality is quite complex. And I didn't even study tables without headers or without long strings that need a "break-word".

Comment: Can I have a reference of this?

Answer (score 3):

there is an option to simulate max-width:

```
simulateMaxWidth: function() {
    this.$el.find('th').css('width', ''); // clear all the width values for every header cell
    this.$el.find('th').each(function(ind, th) {
        var el = $(th);
        var maxWidth = el.attr('max-width');
        if (maxWidth && el.width() > maxWidth) {
            el.css('width', maxWidth + 'px');
        }
    });
}
```

this function can be called on $(window).on('resize', ...) multiple times

```
this.$el
```

represents parent element, in my case I have marionette

for those th elements which should have max-width, there should be a max-width attribute like:

```
<th max-width="120">
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Specify width for each column in `<th>` according to your need.

2) Add word wrap for each `<td>` in `<tr>` of the `<table>`.

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

Answer (score -6):

**it's very easy**

You could add attributes like these

> max-width
>
> max-height

They can be set in html as an attribute or in CSS as a style