# How to use max-width on html colgroup columns?

Tags: html, css

I got a table with 4 columns, A, B, C and D. I want B and C to have a fixed width of `75px` and A to have a max width of `100px`. However I cannot figure out how to accomplish this, is seems that `max-width` is being ignored.

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bt4rzcw2/16/

```
<colgroup>
    <col style="max-width: 100px" />
    <col span="2" style="width: 75px;" />
    <col style="width: auto" />
</colgroup>
```

Comment: Max-width doesn't work like you'd expect it to on table columns, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18367959/table-columns-setting-both-min-and-max-width-with-css

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the below code link? Hope it will work for you.

If you want the fixed-width columns you just need to remove `width: 100%;` from the `table` element.

Please refer to this link:
http://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/5xspwdet/1/

Comment: Oh darn, I need both. Seems like tables don't work the way I thought they could.